# i can not access to my model's attributs in the dynaForm primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

my problem is that i can not access to my  model's attributs in the dynaForm.
(i'm using spring jsf primfaces).

[picture of my xhtml where i have the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATncT.png)

thank you for help.

here is my code

```
public class Colonne {
    private String nomColonne;
    private String typeColonne;
    private int index;

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    public Colonne() {
        super();
    }

    public Colonne(String nomColonne, String typeColonne, int i) {
        super();
        this.nomColonne = nomColonne;
        this.typeColonne = typeColonne;
        this.index=i;
    }

    public String getNomColonne() {
        return nomColonne;
    }

    public void setNomColonne(String nomColonne) {
        this.nomColonne = nomColonne;
    }

    public String getTypeColonne() {
        return typeColonne;
    }

    public void setTypeColonne(String typeColonne) {
        this.typeColonne = typeColonne;
    }
}
```

here is my managedBean

```
public class MonBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5773011533863117274L;
    private GestionTableImpl gestionTable;
    private Table table;
    private  DynaFormModel model;

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public  DynaFormModel initialize() { 
        System.out.println("1");
        model = new DynaFormModel();  

        Colonne col = new Colonne("a","b",0 );  
        DynaFormRow row = model.createRegularRow();  
        row.addControl(col, "columnName");
        row.addControl(col, "columnType"); 
        row.addControl(col, "add");  


        col = new Colonne("c","d",1 );  
        row = model.createRegularRow();    
        row.addControl(col, "columnName");
        row.addControl(col, "columnType"); 
        row.addControl(col, "add");  


        col = new Colonne("e","f", 2);  
        row = model.createRegularRow();  
        row.addControl(col, "columnName");
        row.addControl(col, "columnType"); 
        row.addControl(col, "add");  

        return model;
    }  



    public DynaFormModel getModel() {  
        return model;  
    }  

    public void setModel(DynaFormModel model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Table getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is and IDE thing (warning)... does the code actually run? If so, tag this question as an IDE and not jsf or primefaces one (and it most likely won't get fixed since the IDE does not know about the details how components work (other then default jsf ones)

Comment: it is  resolved :) thank you.. i can run it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `#{monBean.initialize()}` to dynaForm value attribute, use `#{monbean.model}` instead.

Also, you have to change `initialize` method of `MonBean` class to return `void`, and annotate this method with `@PostConstruct`.

This way it won't fail when executing and your IDE wn't complain about it.

Comment: yes i tried that but it does not work .. it give me the same warning .. i try to run my code now and it works !!! thank you for help

Comment: Although you refer to a valid issue, that is not the core of the problem here (there effectively is **no** problem in what is described;-)